# Why doesn't hydrogen peroxide decompose into hydrogen and oxygen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrogen

I'm trying to understand why hydrogen peroxide doesn't decompose into $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{O2}$, but instead into $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have two theoretical decomposition pathways:

$$\ce{H2O2(l) -> H2O(l) + 1/2 O2(g)} \tag{1}$$

$$\ce{H2O2(l) -> H2(g) + O2(g)} \tag{2}$$

The required data (all at $298~\mathrm{K}$) is taken from the appendix of Atkins' *Physical Chemistry*, 9th ed:

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
\hline
\text{Species} & \Delta_\mathrm{f} H^\circ\mathrm{~/~kJ~mol^{-1}} & S^\circ_\mathrm{m} \mathrm{~/~J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}} & \Delta_\mathrm{f} G^\circ\mathrm{~/~kJ~mol^{-1}} \\
\hline
\ce{H2O2(l)} & -187.78 & 109.6 & -120.35 \\
\ce{H2O(l)} & -285.83 & 69.91 & -237.13 \\
\ce{H2(g)} & 0 & 130.684 & 0 \\
\ce{O2(g)} & 0 & 205.138 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

## The short way

The standard Gibbs free energy change of a reaction ($\Delta_\mathrm{r} G^\circ$) can be calculated from the individual standard Gibbs free energies of formation exactly analogously to the enthalpy change:

$$\Delta_\mathrm{r} G^\circ = \sum_J \nu_J[\Delta_\mathrm{f} G^\circ(\ce{J})]$$

So, for reaction 1,

$$\begin{align}
\Delta G^\circ_1 &= [1(-237.13) + \frac{1}{2}(0) - 1(-120.35)]~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} \\
&= -116.78~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}}
\end{align}$$

For reaction 2,

$$\begin{align}
\Delta G^\circ_2 &= [1(0) + 1(0) - 1(-120.35)]~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} \\
&= +120.35~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}}
\end{align}$$

Clearly reaction 1 is favourable and reaction 2 isn't.

---

## The long way

There's absolutely no need to do this, but you could use the "extra" data given above to calculate $\Delta H^\circ$ and $\Delta S^\circ$ for both reactions. You'd get:

$$\begin{align}
\Delta H^\circ_1 &= [1(-285.83) + \frac{1}{2}(0) - 1(-187.78)]~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} \\
&= -98.05 ~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} \\
\Delta H^\circ_2 &= [1(0) + 1(0) - 1(-187.78)]~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} \\
&= +187.78 ~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} \\
\Delta S^\circ_1 &= [1(69.91) + \frac{1}{2}(205.138) - 1(109.6)]~\mathrm{J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}} \\
&= +62.879 ~\mathrm{J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}} \\
\Delta S^\circ_2 &= [1(130.684) + 1(205.138) - 1(109.6)]~\mathrm{J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}} \\
&= +226.222 ~\mathrm{J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}}
\end{align}$$

If you're *only* interested in the final result, you don't need to do all this at all. But it does give you some insight into the difference between the two reactions: reaction 1 is *enthalpically favoured* whereas reaction 2 is *entropically favoured*.

Generally speaking, enthalpy *usually* plays a larger role in determining $\Delta G^\circ$. However, it is not a very good idea to generalise this statement and compare reactions solely on the basis of their $\Delta H^\circ$.

Since $\Delta G^\circ = \Delta H^\circ - T\Delta S^\circ$, and taking $T = 298~\mathrm{K}$,

$$\begin{align}
\Delta G^\circ_1 &= -98.05 ~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} - (298~\mathrm{K})(+62.879 ~\mathrm{J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}}) \\
&= -116.79~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} \\
\Delta G^\circ_2 &= +187.78 ~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} - (298~\mathrm{K})(+226.222 ~\mathrm{J~K^{-1}~mol^{-1}}) \\
&= +120.37~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{-1}} \\
\end{align}$$

consistent with our earlier findings.

Answer (score 1):

The actual equation for the decomposition is:

$\ce{2H2O2}$ $\ce{->}$ $\ce{2H2O}$ + $\ce{O2}$

Yet another form of the equation that you think is supposed to happen is:

$\ce{2H2O2}$ $\ce{->}$ $\ce{2H2}$ + $\ce{2O2}$

---

Using bond enthalpies, it can be calculated that the energy needed to break all the bonds in gaseous hydrogen peroxide ($\ce{H2O2}$)is the summation of the energies need to break the two ($\ce{O-H}$) bonds and the ($\ce{O-O}$)bond. The energies are $\ce{2 * 465 kJ/mol}$ and $\ce{213 kJ/mol}$ respectively.

The extra energy added to the system required to do so for 2 moles of $\ce{H2O2(g)}$ = **2286 kJ**

The total energy required to form 2 mol each of $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ = **1848 kJ**

For $\ce{2H2O2}$ $\ce{->}$ $\ce{2H2}$ + $\ce{2O2}$ to occur, **438 kJ**  must be absorbed in to the system or reaction vessel, i.e. **∆H = +438kJ** — *an endothermic process*.

The energy required to form $\ce{2H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$ = **2358 kJ**

If $\ce{2H2O2}$ $\ce{->}$ $\ce{2H2O}$ + $\ce{O2}$ occurs, **72 kJ** will be absorbed by the reaction vessel, i.e. the reaction has **∆H = -36 kJ/mol of $\ce{2H2O2}$** — *an exothermic process*.

By employing the Gibbs free energy equation (and general rules of thumb regard entropy and temperature), ***exothermic reactions tend to be spontaneous while endothermic reactions are not***. As the reaction producing water and oxygen gas is exothermic, it is also the more "favoured reaction". Even though the change of entropy of $\ce{2H2O2}$ $\ce{->}$ $\ce{2H2}$ + $\ce{2O2}$ is likely to be higher than that of the other reaction, ∆S has less of an impact on ∆G than ∆H does.

---

I used bond enthalpy data from a university chemistry class data sheet [online](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~shultz/Common_Bond_enthalpies.pdf).