# Conversion of H2O2 into H2O

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

If I had $\ce{H2O2}$ in a beaker and I put $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ gas in that beaker, what would happen? $\ce{H2}$ will combine with $\ce{H2O2}$, or a $\ce{O}$ atom in $\ce{H2O2}$ will separate and make bonds with $\ce{H2}$ gas?

Comment: Nothing will happen.

Comment: Why? H2O2 is unstable

Comment: Forget the dihydrogen and dioxygen gas... just leave that jar of H2O2 outside one sunny afternoon and you'll get your H2O ;) [Alternatively you can just heat the jar till all the H2O2 decomposes to H2O]

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42736/disproportionation-of-hydrogen-peroxide

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43233/why-this-doesnt-hydrogen-peroxide-decompose-into-hydrogen-and-oxygen

Comment: Also see [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57622/mechanism-for-hydrogen-peroxide-decomposition) and check the links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Light can cause the hydrogen peroxide to decompose:

$$\ce{H2O2->2 OH}$$

The $\ce{OH}$ can react with $\ce{H2}$

[$$\ce{OH + H2 -> H2O + H}$$](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.430882)

Also, $\ce{OH}$ is an important chemical in atmospheric chemistry. It takes part in several reactions. In the troposphere, it takes part in the following reactions:

$$\ce{OH + CO-> CO2 + H}$$
$$\ce{OH + H2O2-> H2O + HO2}$$
$$\ce{OH + O3-> HO2 + O2}$$
$$\ce{CH4 + OH-> CH3 + O2}$$

The products of these reactions further react with other gases and vapors in the atmosphere. You can learn more about it [here](http://acmg.seas.harvard.edu/people/faculty/djj/book/bookchap11.html#pgfId=106009).

The behavior of chemicals is complex. "What will happen?" is a question that is almost always too broad.

**Source:**

[Introduction to Atmospheric Chemistry by Daniel J. Jacob, Princeton University Press, 1999.](http://acmg.seas.harvard.edu/people/faculty/djj/book/)